# How send data from server to JavaScript without request with flask?

Tags: javascript, flask

I wrote the desktop app that work locally. Now I try to create the same app but with a frontend that will be run on web browser. I got already basic knowledge about web development but I still don't fully understand how to implement correct communication between frontend and backend.
In my desktop app in frontend I have callback functions that backend execute when some date updated.

The first question, is it possible to send the data from server to the webpage (JavaScript func.) without request from the webpage?
A have a two case, rapidly update data and async update data? The main purpose is using that data in JavaScript func first.

And the second question, if I don't want change data on server, but just need request some variables from server to use it in JavaScript what the best way? Should I use "POST" method for that?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use `webSockets`, this allows the server to send data to the client without the client requesting it.   There are other options too, like long poling, or server-sent events, but webwockets I'd say is the easier option, as it's bi-directional.

Comment: Its the same as on your mobile app. Only difference is that the client is not your app but the browser. If you want realtime communication you need websockets.
Generally just read/watch any basic HTTP tutorial to get an understanding of how it works and what the methods are for.

Comment: Thx! Got that idea! Will discover in that direction!

Answer (score 3):

To send data from the server to JavaScript without an explicit request using Flask, you can use Server-Sent Events (SSE). SSE is a simple and efficient way to establish a unidirectional communication channel from the server to the client over a single HTTP connection.

Comment: SSE related only for Flask or is it a general concept?